# Button ToolTip binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In order to change the tooltip text of a button, I am using the following code:

**ViewModel**

```
private string _toolTipText;

public string ToolTipText
{
    get
    {
        return _toolTipText;
    }
    set
    {
        _toolTipText= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Button Name="btnDoSomething" Width="21" Height="21" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}">                        
         <Button.ToolTip>
             <ToolTip Content="{Binding ToolTipText}" />
         </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Somehow when I change the ToolTipText and the RaisePropertyChanged is called, the ToolTip still displays the old text. Instead of using the Button.ToolTip tag I tried the ToolTipService.ToolTip and TextBlock as well. It has the same result; old text is displayed.

**View (code snippet 1)**

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip Content="{Binding ToolTipText}" />
</ToolTipService.ToolTip >
```

**View (code snippet 2)**

```
<Button.ToolTip>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=ToolTipText}" />
</Button.ToolTip>
```

When I hover the mouse over the ToolTip of the button, it doesn't call the 'getter' of ToolTipText.

Could you explain to me what is going wrong and how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

*Note: I searched for solutions on Google and StackOverflow, but the proposed solutions didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @ASh: I tried it as well, but the result is the same: old text is displayed.

Comment: I solved the issue. The 'Mode=TwoWay' was missing. Anyway thanks for the help!